# webpack: multiple input with multiple file-type outputs

Tags: javascript, sass, webpack, ecmascript-6

I have been able to compile "es6 standard" js files into native js using one entry point, I've also been able to use multiple entries to compile multiple files. Example:

*webpack.config.js*

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        front: "./static/src/js/Front.js",
        account: "./static/src/js/Account.js"
    },
    output: {
        path: "./static/dist",
        filename: "[name]-bundle.js"
    }
};
```

I have understood the concept of using modules/plugins to compile other files, with a little bit more...

```
modules: {
    loaders: [
      { tests: '/\.(css|scss)$/', loader: 'css-loader|style-loader'}
    ]
}
```

These solutions compile my files into JavaScript only, including my `styles (scss, sass, css)`.

I am looking for a solution where I will have two (or multiple) different entry files, that each will produce its own output file with its own file-type (not just `.js`). I would not mind having multiple config modules. Thanks...

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking, from what I see you already have a way to extract your source code into multiple files, are you talking about removing the stylesheets from the bundle?

Comment: Yes! That's what I want to do - "Remove the stylesheets from the bundle and put it inside a css file"

Answer (score 2):

Since your code is in SCSS, you need the SCSS loader and CSS loader, you also need `extract-text-webpack-plugin`, this is what brings out any text you have in the bundle into a separate file.

Also, because I know you will want to move the image and font files from the bundle I went ahead to add test for extracting the images/fonts, for those you will need to install `file-loader`. I hope that helps

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractText = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

const extractCss= new ExtractText({ filename: 'styles/vendors.css' });
const extractSass = new ExtractText({ filename: 'styles/site.css' });

module.exports = (env) => {
  return {
    entry: {
      main: path.resolve(__dirname, '../', 'src', 'Front.js'),
    },
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../', 'dist'),
      filename: 'js/[name]-bundle.js',
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        { test: /\.css/, use: extractCss.extract(['css-loader']) },
        { test: /\.scss/, exclude: /node_modules/, use: extractSass.extract(['css-loader', 'sass-loader']) },

        { test: /\.(png|jpg)$/, exclude: /node_modules/, use: 'file-loader?outputPath=images/&publicPath=../'},
        { test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9]+)?$/, use: 'file-loader?outputPath=fonts/&publicPath=../'},
      ]
    },
    resolve: {
      modules: ['node_modules'],
    },
    plugins: [
      extractCss,
      extractSass,
    ]
  }
}
```

`PS: I am in a hurry out, so I just cooked this up fast, when I come back I will review, in case you find any bugs, just comment below.`

Comment: Thanks, this works nice except for the assets inside the `scss` files of other vendors like bootstrap. I get some error like this (this is just a little, the error message is so long)
`Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot' `,

Comment: You can take those out if you are not making use of any fonts

Comment: I'm using the font files